# What target to set when Google Maps and Admob to be used Together

Tags: android, google-maps, admob

I am developing an android application in which I need to use Google Maps and Admob together. I am facing errors as the way I have specified the target in manifest and project.properties file, it only allows me to use either google maps or admob.

The min sdk and target version as specified in manifest file is like this

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="13"
```

In project.properties, its specified as `"target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:8"`

On many blogs and questions on stack overflow, I have seen people fixing the admob issue by specifying the android target version to 13 or higher. However in my case, if I do this, it starts giving errors related to MapActivity.

Please suggest what target levels should I specify in my manifest file and project.properties so I can make both maps and admob work.

Many thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using in my project minSdkVersion="4" targetSdkVersion="8" and I'm added Android 3.0 Google APIs, I had some problems in the past but I only had to check the external library, you can check it too. Sometimes the library takes time in be included and you can have problems with MapActivity.

Comment: Margge, Thanks for your response. Could you please elaborate a little more as to what target should I specify in my project.properties file. I need to make both admob and maps work in my app. The version for admob sdk that I am using is 4.3.1. and the google api target is 2.2

Comment: You can specify target android-10, I'm using admob version 4.3.1 too

Comment: when I do this, it affects the map activity and the app doesnt compile. In your app, does Admob and Google Maps both work correctly? If yes, can you please suggest what target and min sdk version you have specified in AndroidManifest file. Thanks..